# Data Mining SSE Via Clusters K

Tags: cluster-analysis, weka, k-means

I'm working on WEKA with K-Means and Clustering.
In general I'm examine the different algorithms on a dataset for project.
I can't decide what the optimal SSE/Clusters ratio i should choose.
In theory, as I increase the clusters the SSE decrease, but Until where ?
Found some finger rule that K = (n/2)^0.5, Can anyone second this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that Weka doesn't have a lot of clustering. It is primarily a classification tool.

Sum of Squares is a *very* k-means centric measure. Don't bother to use this measure with any other algorithm. This is overfitting: it's the measure that k-means optimizes for, so of course it will come out best (and by adding another cluster, it will be able to further improve on this measure, which comes at no surprise).

If you want to evaluate the quality of a clustering, the most reliable (although also questionable) way is to use a labeled data set.

Comment: I've read that i might use MakeDensityBasedClusterer to find log likelihood, but again, if i increase clusers the likelihood will increase (for example, 5 gave -28, 8 gave -27 and 10 gave -25)

Comment: Yes. That is typical for internal evaluation. You will need to find a tradeoff, as a more complex model will usually allow a more detailed (but not necessarily better!) model of the data. Some measures (BIC?) try to strike such a tradeoff, but I'm not convinced that it is much better. It's still evaluating clusters how well they fit to a rather constrained model.